# change bootstrap grid direction dynamically ( ltr to rtl or reverese)

Tags: php, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, right-to-left

We are making a site which  will work both Rtl and Ltr ( En and Fa ).

We want to use tweeter bootstrap (3.*) .

Our mvc is made upon php .

Is it possible to use bootstrap which it's grid flow order is  Rtl  if the site language is fa , and use Ltr when the language is English ?

By **language** , I mean this : www.example.com/en   or www.example.com/fa

when it is /en , we must use bootstrap which is Ltr (Left to right )

when it is /fa , we must use bootstrap which is Rtl (Right to left)

I know there are some bootstrap themes that I can use which are Rtl , but how can I use both rtl and ltr and changed within them dynamically ? ( maybe after a page refresh site direction goes Rtl or Ltr !!) ?

Comment: Kinda confused, what is the question exactly?

Comment: @mongoer Yes it's possible. One option could be to `<link>` to LTR/RTL version based on the request by PHP.

Comment: woah. Love this question. bookmarked :)

Answer (score 4):

Simply change `float:left;` to `float:right;` in grid system when `html` tag has `dir='rtl'`.

Here is the css:

```
html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-xs-1, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-xs-2, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-xs-3, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-xs-4, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-xs-5, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-xs-6, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-xs-7, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-xs-8, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-xs-9, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-xs-10, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-xs-11, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-xs-12 {
  float: right;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-sm-1, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-sm-2, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-sm-3, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-sm-4, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-sm-5, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-sm-6, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-sm-7, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-sm-8, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-sm-9, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-sm-10, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-sm-11, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-sm-12 {
    float: right;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-md-1, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-md-2, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-md-3, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-md-4, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-md-5, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-md-6, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-md-7, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-md-8, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-md-9, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-md-10, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-md-11, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-md-12 {
    float: right;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1170px) {
  html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-lg-1, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-lg-2, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-lg-3, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-lg-4, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-lg-5, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-lg-6, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-lg-7, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-lg-8, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-lg-9, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-lg-10, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-lg-11, html[dir="rtl"] .row > .col-lg-12 {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you man for a great answer, by using this css script I can just applied when I needed

Answer (score 2):

You can modify CSS rules "on the fly", attached here is a function, it modifies the major classes for Bootstrap 3 like `col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-(1-12), col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-push-(1-12), col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-pull-(1-12), col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-offset-(1-12)`, there are many more classes to be modified but i needed only those.

All you need to do is call the function `layout.setDirection('rtl')` or `layout.setDirection('ltr')` and it will change the CSS Rules.

Should work on all browsers (IE>=9).

```
        var layout = {};
        layout.setDirection = function (direction) {
            layout.rtl = (direction === 'rtl');
            document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style.direction = direction;
            var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
            var modifyRule = function (rule) {
                if (rule.style.getPropertyValue(layout.rtl ? 'left' : 'right') && rule.selectorText.match(/\.col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-push-\d\d*/)) {
                    rule.style.setProperty((layout.rtl ? 'right' : 'left'), rule.style.getPropertyValue((layout.rtl ? 'left' : 'right')));
                    rule.style.removeProperty((layout.rtl ? 'left' : 'right'));
                }
                if (rule.style.getPropertyValue(layout.rtl ? 'right' : 'left') && rule.selectorText.match(/\.col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-pull-\d\d*/)) {
                    rule.style.setProperty((layout.rtl ? 'left' : 'right'), rule.style.getPropertyValue((layout.rtl ? 'right' : 'left')));
                    rule.style.removeProperty((layout.rtl ? 'right' : 'left'));
                }
                if (rule.style.getPropertyValue(layout.rtl ? 'margin-left' : 'margin-right') && rule.selectorText.match(/\.col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-offset-\d\d*/)) {
                    rule.style.setProperty((layout.rtl ? 'margin-right' : 'margin-left'), rule.style.getPropertyValue((layout.rtl ? 'margin-left' : 'margin-right')));
                    rule.style.removeProperty((layout.rtl ? 'margin-left' : 'margin-right'));
                }
                if (rule.style.getPropertyValue('float') && rule.selectorText.match(/\.col-(xs|sm|md|lg)-\d\d*/)) {
                    rule.style.setProperty('float', (layout.rtl ? 'right' : 'left'));
                }
            };
            try {
                for (var i = 0; i < styleSheets.length; i++) {
                    var rules = styleSheets[i].cssRules || styleSheets[i].rules;
                    if (rules) {
                        for (var j = 0; j < rules.length; j++) {
                            if (rules[j].type === 4) {
                                var mediaRules = rules[j].cssRules || rules[j].rules
                                for (var y = 0; y < mediaRules.length; y++) {
                                    modifyRule(mediaRules[y]);
                                }
                            }
                            if (rules[j].type === 1) {
                                modifyRule(rules[j]);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (e) {
                // Firefox might throw a SecurityError exception but it will work
                if (e.name !== 'SecurityError') {
                    throw e;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just flipping all float:left; to float:right on the major grid entities and serving that as a Rtl specialized CSS file / override?

Comment: Yeap , and consider it works this way , How am I going to do all this float left and right dynamically with only one condition ?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you some hint for scripting this in JavaScript until the native support in feature versions of Bootstrap framework.
you can use pull and push features in grid system in Tweeter Bootstrap. for changing the order of grids. here's an example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

You can create a script to check the language and add appropriate push and pull classes to the grids.